# Reassign zBoard keyboard in win10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I've had a zBoard for a decade now and it has been great! However, just recently my numlock and extra wasd-pad stoped behaving like they used to. Been scratching my head and trying different things to return it to how it was before, without any luck.

[zBoard keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDzZy.jpg)

As you can see the keyboard has a "first person shooter"-section to it's left and a standard numpad to its right. Those have stopped working as expected. "e" on the fps-pad now opens "search windows", "w" now opens my default browser with it's homepage and my numpad has just stopped working as a numpad with numbers, it's just "home", "delete", "insert" etc even if the numpad-lamp is lit.

I've tried SharpKeys and Keymapper but they can't recognize my wasd-pads keys. I'm really new when it comes to regedit but currently that seems like my only option, would be so simple if the wasd-pads keys is mapped to their letters so to speak.

Is there any good keymapper program for this?
How could I change this via regedit? And how can I identify they keys in that case?

And in worst case scenario; is there any good modern replacement for zBoard? I would like to only have the wasd-pad separate.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

It was Windows 10 security update KB4034674 which caused this issue.

I've also got this problem, and have tried a few of the same things as you. Haven't found a a permanent solution yet, though the [Windows Update rollback mentioned here works for me.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/merc-stealth-zboard-not-working-after-windows-10/c444c8ec-14cc-4df7-b0ec-6767b6bedb93?auth=1)

Instructions to uninstall in the second half of [this article.](https://www.howtogeek.com/235474/how-to-roll-back-builds-and-uninstall-updates-on-windows-10/) Rolling back the specified update fixed things for now, hopefully MS provides a permanent fix, but its a good stopgap for now. Also make sure to pause your win update or disable it in another way. You can do this with Windows Update -> Advanced options -> Pause Updates. (Though this will only work for 35 days).